# In form data, pass info about which button was clicked -- after confirmation modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The click event on my submit button triggers a confirmation modal.

When the user clicks on the confirmation button, the form is sent without the original submit button data, which I need.

Simplified code:

```
<form action="/action" method="post">
    <!-- inputs -->
    <button type="submit" name="foo" class="with-confirmation-modal" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.with-confirmation-modal', function() {
    $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $modal = $('#modal');
    $modal.on('click', 'button[type=submit]', function() {
        // form is sent without the info about which button
        // was clicked prior to modal
        $form.submit();
        return false;
    });
    $modal.modal('show');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

What's a good way to deal with this ?

Comment: $(this).closest('form') is giving the correct form ??

Comment: if your submit button contains data you need, put that data in a hidden text input, that way you dont need to alter the submit event, then you dont need to click handler. submit button values dont get posted

Comment: @atmd I am not trying to get the value of the submit button. When you post a form clicking on <button type="submit" name="foo" />, data posted includes the name of the button : ...&foo=&... . That's what I need. Thanks anyway, I will indeed go the route of adding a hidden input to include it, that's what I was thinking about as well.

Comment: @Dreamweaver yes. I'll add a bit more detail in the question.

Comment: Do you have working code?  Could we see it? (jsfiddle, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post a form clicking on

```
<button type="submit" name="foo" />
```

data posted includes the name of the button :

```
...&foo=&...
```

This behaviour is broken by the confirmation popup. Here we simulate it by adding a hidden input with the name of the clicked button before calling $form.submit().

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.with-confirmation-modal', function() {
    var $clickedBtn = $(this);
    var $form = $clickedBtn.closest('form');
    $modal = $('#credit-headsup-modal');
    $modal.on('click', 'button[type=submit]', function() {
        $(this).parent('.btn-wrapper').addClass('btn-wrapper--active');
        $(this).siblings('.btn-loading').show();
        // Pass info about which btn was clicked prior to modal
        // by adding a hidden input with same name as btn
        $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="'+$clickedBtn.attr('name')+'" value="">');
        $form.submit();
        return false;
    });
    $modal.modal('show');
    return false;
</script>
```

If there is a better way, please share.